# how to search the data based on month in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to search the data based on

1. By Month
2. By quater
3. By Half Year
4. By year in my revenue report.

Can any one help me how to do? My revenue report displays the booking information
in controller.

```
def revenue
  @bookings = Booking.all
  @bookings = Booking.where(currency: params[:currency]) if param[:currency].present?
end
```

My revenue.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xlg-1">
 <%= form_tag revenue_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= select_tag(:currency, options_for_select(["USD", "EUR"]), onchange: 'this.form.submit();', class: "form-control custom-select" , include_blank: true ) %>
 <% end %>   
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xlg-2">
  <%= select_month(Date.today)%>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xlg-2">
     <select class="custom-select" data-style="form-control btn-secondary">
    <option>By quater</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xlg-2">
  <select class="custom-select" data-style="form-control btn-secondary">
    <option>By Halfyear</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xlg-2">
  <select class="custom-select" data-style="form-control btn-secondary">
    <option>By Year</option>
  </select>
 </div>

 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="demo-foo-addrow" class="table m-t-30 table-hover no-wrap contact-list no-paging footable-loaded footable" data-page-size="2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="footable-sortable">#<span class="footable-sort-indicator"></span></th>
            <th class="footable-sortable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="minimal-checkbox-1">
            </th>
            <th class="footable-sortable">First Name<span class="footable-sort-indicator"></span></th>
            <th class="footable-sortable">Last Name<span class="footable-sort-indicator"></span></th>
            <th class="footable-sortable">Email<span class="footable-sort-indicator"></span></th>
            <th class="footable-sortable">Status<span class="footable-sort-indicator"></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= booking.id %></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "bookings[booking_ids][]", booking.id %></td>
            <td><%= booking.first_name %></td>
            <td><%= booking.last_name %></td>
            <td><%= booking.email %></td>
            <td><%= booking.status %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read about how to query data with ActiveRecord in Rails and compose the queries for your use-case. The code doesn't show any attempt at code or research to reach to answer.

Comment: @kiddorails il read about that. But i have tried searching about this and tried doing <%= form_tag revenue_path, :method => 'get' do %>
                            <%= select_tag(:currency, options_for_select(["US", "UK"]), onchange: 'this.form.submit();', class: "form-control custom-select" , include_blank: true ) %>
<% end %>  and also give search params in controller but i dint get the result and thot this is nt the right way to solve the prob. Thats the reason i posted by removing all my trials.

Comment: this is from the perspective of frontend for originating the request; the logic for query will go in `def revenue` method. You will need to read the parameters and form the query accordingly

Comment: ya i know. Forming query is the thing i am getting confused. I had given the logic query in the same method like this @bookings = @booking.where(currency: params[:currency]) if params[:currency].present? but it tells undefined method where for nil class

Comment: Good. change `@booking.where` to `Booking.where`. And edit the question with these code examples and what error was given.

Comment: @kiddorails. I have edited. But this change doesnt give error but it doesnt show the required result. Is this query right?

Comment: Check the params to check if you are actually getting right value in `params[:currency]`. Check your rails server log (next line after `Started GET...`) to see the parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173497/discussion-between-amy-and-kiddorails).

Comment: this could be useful: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Comment: @apneadiving Thanks for that. il look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on debugging together with OP, found that the given method actually does much more than written. In last line of method, `@booking = Booking.paginate(:per_page => 100)` was being done which dissolved the query set generated earlier.

The final variant looked something like this:

```
def revenue
    @bookings = Booking.all
    if params[:currency].present?
      @bookings = @bookings.where(currency: params[:currency])
    end
    if params[:search].present?
      @bookings = @bookings.where('first_name like ?', "%#{params[:search]}}")
    end

    if params['date'] && params['date']['month']
      @selected_date = Date.parse('2018-'+ params['date']['month'].to_s + '-01')
      @bookings = @bookings.where('extract(month from created_at) = ?', params['date']['month'])
    end

    if params['date'] && params['date']['year']
      @selected_year = params['date'] && params['date']['year'] ? Date.parse( params['date']['year'].to_s + '-01') : Date.today
      @bookings = Booking.where('extract(year  from created_at) = ?',  params['date']['year'])
    end

    @per_page = params[:per_page] || Booking.per_page || 20
    @bookings = @bookings.paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
end
```